# Paginacion de un nav-tabs

Tags: laravel-5, bootstrap-4

tengo una un tab que se divide en 3, hasta ahi super, también a esto le agrego mi paginación y me funciona, pero mi idea es que cuando pase a la siguiente pagina, me quede en el tab que estoy trabajando y no vuelva al primero.  Tengo el siguiente código:

Este es de la paginacion

```
<ul class="pagination pagination-flat align-self-center">
                        @if($list->lastItem()>25)
                            <li class="page-item"><a href="{{$list->previousPageUrl()}}{{($menor!="")?"&menor=$menor":''}}{{($tabsel!="")?"&tabsel=$tabsel":""}}" class="page-link"><i class="icon-arrow-left12"></i></a></li>
                        @endif
                        <li class="page-item"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="page-link">{{$list->lastItem()}} de {{$list->total()}}</a></li>
                        @if($list->hasMorePages())
                            <li class="page-item"><a href="{{$list->nextPageUrl()}}{{($menor!="")?"&menor=$menor":''}}{{($tabsel!="")?"&tabsel=$tabsel":""}}" class="page-link"><i class="icon-arrow-right13"></i></a></li>
                        @endif
                    </ul>
```

Mi tab es la siguiente:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link @if($tabsel==5) active show @endif" name="5"  id="nw_trab-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nw_trab" role="tab" aria-controls="nw_trab" aria-selected="true">Test 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link @if($tabsel==4) active show @endif" name="4" id="personal-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#personal" role="tab" aria-controls="personal" aria-selected="false">Test 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link @if($tabsel==6) active show @endif" name="6" id="personal-tab-re" data-toggle="tab" href="#personal_re" role="tab" aria-controls="personal-re" aria-selected="false">Test 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Y para poder detectar el tipo de tab que selecciono tengo el siguiente codigo, con el cual me entrega el posicionamiento.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
            var tabsel= $(e.target).attr("name") // activated tab
            alert(tabsel);
        });
       });
</script>
```

Pero mi gran duda viene aqui, porque me gustaria pasar mi variable tabsel en la paginacion, pero no puedo traspasar de js a php.  O no se si existe otra forma de realizar lo que necesito.  EStoy trabajando con bootraps y laravel